# Source port 0 Destination port 0

Tags: logging

I am seeing logging information on my network of a source port of 0 going to a destination port of 0.  Does anyone know why this occurs?

I also see numerous source ports going to a single destination port when examining my logs which also raises questions.

Usually when it's the other way around the indication is that you have scanning occurring.  Yet I am unsure of what my currently logs are indicating by having numerous source ports going to a single destination port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is generated accidentally due to programming applicantion as per https://www.lifewire.com/port-0-in-tcp-and-udp-818145

This could also mean that attackers are attempting to breach or do a port scan on your network.